# TVOS TVML XMLHttpRequest memory leak crashes application

Tags: memory-leaks, xmlhttprequest, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I have a simple TVML app that displays shop-floor status data, the JS hits a webservice every 60 seconds and pulls an updated TVML string and loads it to the DOM. It works great for about 4 hours then crashes due to a memory leak caused by `XMLHttpRequest` not being deposed of properly. I've tried various ways to release the object, but nothing seems to have any affect.  Any suggestions?

Apple TV device log error is: 90 seconds cpu time over 90 seconds (100% cpu average), exceeding limit of 50% CPU over 180 seconds

```
App.onLaunch = function (options) {
    var ip = options.IP;
    var refreshRate = options.REFRESH_RATE;

    //reload js every 15 minutes
    setTimeout(function () { App.reload() }, 900000);

    //refresh at passed in interval
    setInterval(function () { getTemplate(ip) }, refreshRate);

    loadingMessage(ip);
    getTemplate(ip);
}

function pushDoc(doc) {
    if (doc != null) {
        navigationDocument.clear();
        navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
    }
}

function getTemplate(ip) {
    try {
        var url = "http://GetTemplate?ip=" + ip;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            pushDoc(request.responseXML);
            delete request;
            request = null;
            }
        };

        request.responseType = "document";
        request.open("GET", url);
        request.send();
    }
    catch (err) {
        errorMessage(ip, "getTemplate()", err.message)
    }
}

function loadingMessage(ip) {
    var loadingString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
    loadingString += "<document>";
    loadingString += "<alertTemplate>";
    loadingString += "<title>IP: " + ip + " - " + now() + "</title>";
    loadingString += "<description>Loading...</description>";
    loadingString += "</alertTemplate>";
    loadingString += "</document>";

    var loading = new DOMParser();
    var doc = loading.parseFromString(loadingString, "application/xml");
    pushDoc(doc);
}

function errorMessage(ip, func, err) {
    var errorString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
    errorString += "<document>";
    errorString += "<alertTemplate>";
    errorString += "<title>IP: " + ip + " - " + now() + "</title>";
    errorString += "<description>" + func + " failed! Error is: " + err + "</description>";
    errorString += "</alertTemplate>";
    errorString += "</document>";

    var error = new DOMParser();
    var doc = error.parseFromString(errorString, "application/xml");
    pushDoc(doc);
}

function now() {
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var datetime = ((currentdate.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/"
        + (currentdate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
        + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "
        + (currentdate.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
        + (currentdate.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
        + (currentdate.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentdate.getSeconds();

    return datetime;
}
```